# ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.BROWSERS_PK) violated

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'm working on a C# project where I'm trying to insert a record using the following SQL against an Oracle database:

```
String Qry = INSERT INTO browsers (browsers.browser,browsers.engine,browsers.platform,browsers.version,browsers.grade) VALUES ('Alans browser','Gecko','every','1.0','U') RETURNING id INTO :ID
```

I'm following example code at: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server-cs-conversion/insert-returning-clause

My code is as follows:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(...);
OracleCommand cmd = null;
...
cmd = new OracleCommand(Qry, conn);
OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter();
prm = new OracleParameter(":ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this line throws error
query.setNewRecordID(cmd.Parameters[":ID"].Value.ToString());
...
```

Naturally, the id column of the browsers table is set with Sequence and Trigger to auto increment on any insert.  I don't understand why I'm getting the error when I'm not trying to set the id column.  I'm just trying to retrieve the id value given to the new record.

Uddate:  Following is the SQL commands to create the sequence and trigger:

Sequence:

`CREATE SEQUENCE  "SYSTEM"."BROWSERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999   INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;`

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger BROWSERS_TRG  
before insert on "SYSTEM"."BROWSERS" 
for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if :NEW."ID" is null then 
         select BROWSERS_SEQ.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the status of your trigger is ENABLED by querying the view, user_triggers? I assume the trigger is a similar "before insert" trigger and that it inserts the NEXTVAL of the browsers_seq?

Comment: I've added the code for the sequence and trigger above.  I'm pretty sure they're setup properly.  I'm not sure how to query the view as you put it. Can you tell me what the query looks like so I can test?

Comment: I would run a query like this, `SELECT *
FROM user_triggers
WHERE table_name = 'BROWSERS'
AND trigger_name = 'BROWSERS_TRG'`

Comment: OK.  I ran the query. It was successful. The status column states that it is enabled.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure the status column indicates that it is 'ENABLED'. The error indicates that this does not appear to be working.

Comment: Ok. So how do we make it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61140/discussion-between-patrick-and-alan).

Comment: OK.  I was gone for a while, but I'll meet you in chat now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your sequence (I could not compile as is).  I took the NOPARTITION out of it and it worked.

I created a similar scenario in my SCOTT (sample) schema as follows:

```
 SCOTT@dev> CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP2"
  2    (
  3      "EMPNO"    NUMBER(4,0),
  4      "ENAME"    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  5      "JOB"      VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),
  6      "MGR"      NUMBER(4,0),
  7      "HIREDATE" DATE,
  8      "SAL"      NUMBER(7,2),
  9      "COMM"     NUMBER(7,2),
 10      "DEPTNO"   NUMBER(2,0)
 11    )
 12    TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

Table created.

SCOTT@dev> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."EMP2_EMPNO" ON "SCOTT"."EMP2"
  2    (
  3      "EMPNO"
  4    )
  5    TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

Index created.

SCOTT@dev> set define off;
SCOTT@dev> ALTER TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP2" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO");

Table altered.

SCOTT@dev>  CREATE SEQUENCE EMP2_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE  ;

Sequence created.

SCOTT@dev> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMP2_TRG before
  2    INSERT ON SCOTT.EMP2 FOR EACH row BEGIN IF inserting THEN IF :NEW.EMPNO IS NULL THEN
  3    SELECT EMP2_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.EMPNO FROM dual;
  4  END IF;
  5  END IF;
  6  END;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SCOTT@dev> commit;

Commit complete.

SCOTT@dev> INSERT INTO EMP2
  2  (ENAME)
  3  VALUES
  4  ('FRED')
  5  /

1 row created.

SCOTT@dev> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Consequently, the sequence seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  This morning I was able to revisit this issue and figured there had to be a way to query the sequence itself and figure out what value it currently holds.  By running select browsers_seq.currval from dual I was able to see the last value which was 48.  I performed a delete of all records greater than 48 from the table, and since there were only a few, reinserted them one at a time without error.  So the issue is solved.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that sequence AND trigger are set correctly? Usually I don't use trigger, but just a sequencer.nextval directly into the query. If you need to use the generated id in other portion of code, you can perform a 'select sequence.nextval from dual' and cache the results

Comment: OK I changed the query to: INSERT INTO browsers (browsers.ID,browsers.browser,browsers.engine,browsers.platform,browsers.version,browsers.grade) VALUES (BROWSERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'Alans browser','Gecko','every','1.0','U');  I'm testing this SQL statement by itself in SQL Developer to see what happens. By itself, it is generating the error.  Am I missing something in the query string?  The sequence is definitely named BROWSERS_SEQ

Comment: the table is not empty.  there are 59 records in there starting with id=1 for the first record.

Comment: So probably your sequence is starting from an id that is already present in the table. To increment sequence, alter sequence xx increment by xx

Comment: Well I ran the following: ALTER SEQUENCE "SYSTEM"."BROWSERS_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  INCREMENT BY 1;  followed by an INSERT statement, but it didn't help.  Same error message.